# How can I code up my own element so that it responds to a change in a DynamicResource?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this XAML where the Label's text color changes whenever my application changes the value of the DynamicResource TextColor

```
<Label TextColor="{DynamicResource TextColor}" />
```

I understand that I can create my own custom label like this:

```
namespace Ja.Templates
{
    public class Label : Label
    {
        public Label()
        {
            Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("TextColor", out object textColor);
            TextColor = (Color)textColor;
        }
    }
}

<t:Label TextColor="{DynamicResource TextColor}" />
```

My problem is that the Template.Label does not respond to changes in the DynamicResource TextColor.

How can I add this functionality to my Label?  Note that this is just an example, my actual code is more complicated than just creating a label but I try to give the simplest code possible for this question.

Comment: You are creating `Ja.Templates.Label` but your Xaml is using `Xamarin.Forms.Label` (assumably from the Xamarin.Forms namespace and not your own namespace)

Comment: yeah this was just an example where the first Xamarin.Forms.Label will take the Dynamic resource, but my own Ja.Templates.Label won't take / respond to changes in the DynamicResource once the object has been created.

Comment: What is your actual XAML then?

Comment: The XAML I am using is <t:Label TextColor="{DynamicResource TextColor}" />  This gives me the correct TextColor but does not track changes to the DynamicResource?

Comment: then you can just `Resources["TextColor"] = "Red";` (no need to use a subclassed Label)

Comment: But I am using Label just as an example to make the question clear.  The object I create has a lot more going on than just this label. What I'm hoping to find out is how I can make my object respond to changes in the DynamicResource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'm hoping to find out is how I can make my object respond to changes in the DynamicResource

You can assign the property and dynamic resource name within your .ctor if you want:

```
public MyLabel()
{
    SetDynamicResource(Label.FontColorProperty, "TextColor");
}
```

Then in your Form' code-behind assign a value to the dynamic resource:

```
Resources["TextColor"] = "Red";
```